# Button not highlighting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I create a set of prefabs at runtime via script. They are held in an array called newObj. Each one has some text UIs and some buttons, which I retrieve with GetComponentsInChildren. When a user clicks the first button in the prefab, I want to run a function that changes the text of the button and highlights that button.

Everything is working except the button doesn't highlight.

```
public void SelectPlayer(int rowSelected)
{
    var buttons = newObj[rowSelected].GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();
    var texts = newObj[rowSelected].GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();

    texts[0].text = "1";

    buttons[0].Select();
    buttons[0].OnDeselect(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops. I'm still new to Unity and forgot that Unity sets the default highlight color to white (for some reason). Once I changed it for my prefab using the editor, all was well.

Comment: Great. Close this topic so it's cleaned up